# Export separate objects as separate .obj

Tags: export, objects, file-format

I want to export a selection of objects as .obj. I want each object as its own .obj. Is there a way to export individual .obj for each object selected? There does not seem to be an python reference for exporting, nor is a command echoed when I export a single .obj

[image]